# Finding the Period of Sums of Sine and Cosine

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I have reviewed [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314163/understanding-proof-of-period-of-sinax-b-coscx-d) already, but I did not find the explanation to be as natural / intuitive as I would have liked, so I have tried rewriting the proof.

Let us consider the function $f(x) = \sin(\frac{a}{b}x) + \cos(\frac{c}{d}x)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and the fractions are expressed in lowest terms. We want to find the period of this function.

Notice that the sine component of $f(x)$ has a period of $\frac{2\pi b}{a}$ while the cosine component has a period of $\frac{2\pi d}{c}$. For $f(x)$ to complete one period both $\sin$ and $\cos$ must go through an integral number of periods.
So, let $z\in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $n =\frac{az}{2\pi b}$ and $m=\frac{cz}{2\pi d}$ are integers.
Our goal is to determine the smallest possible integers $n$ and $m$, for a choice of real $z$. Based on this, we choose $$z = \frac{2\pi\cdot\text{lcm}(b,d)}{\gcd(a,c)}$$

To verify this choice, observe the following:

- For $n$ and $m$ to both be integers, $\frac{z_1}{2\pi b}$ and $\frac{z_1}{2\pi d}$ must be integers. By the definition of LCM, the smallest value $z_1$ that satisfies this is $2 \pi \cdot \text{lcm}(b,d)$.
- We can further reduce $n$ and $m$ by eliminating common factors between $a$ and $c$, we capture all common factors by dividing through by $\gcd(a,c)$.

Is this correct? Further, is there a more rigorous way to verify the choice if this does work? Thanks.